# Mostrar datos de una relacion m2m en un template

Tags: python, django

Tengo un modelo **Lista** que puede tener muchos miembros/usuarios

```
class List(models.Model):
    name    = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Nombre")
    items   = models.ManyToManyField(Item, blank=True)
    user    = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete= models.CASCADE) #ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name="members")
    desc    = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Descripción")    # Cambiar 
    image   = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Imagen", upload_to="lists", blank=True, null=True, default="no_list_icon.png")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Fecha de creacion')
    updated = models.DateField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Fecha de edición")
```

Cómo puedo mostrar los valores de esa relacion ManyToMany en el template? En el modelo del formulario tengo lo siguiente:

```
class ListForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = List
        fields = ['name', 'desc', 'image', 'members']
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control w-100 mt-3 mb-3', 'placeholder': "Nombre de tu nueva lista", }),
            'desc': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control mt-3 w-100 mb-3', 'rows':5, 'placeholder': "Añade una descripción"}),
            'image' : forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control-file mt-5 mb-3', 'accept':'image/* ',}),
        }
```

Para hacer pruebas accedo al admin y asigno algunos usuarios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez en el template, quiero mostrar solamente aquellos usuarios asignados. Lo he intentado con:

```
{{ form.members }}
```

Pero aparece la misma caja

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si lo intento hacer con un bucle for

```
{% for member in form.members %}
    {{ member }}
{% endfor %}
```

Me aparecen los mismos nombres, es decir, todos los usuarios que existen en la base de datos y cada uno de los nombres dentro de un tag

```
<option value="5" selected="">laura</option>
<option value="6" selected="">marcos</option>
<option value="7" selected="">marcosh</option>
<option value="8">testo</option>
```

Usando un bucle, la única forma para diferenciarlos es comprobando si cada uno de los valores tiene el atributo **selected** y, con Javascript, podría eliminarlos del DOM, pero no quiero caer en malas prácticas y sería ineficiente comprobar una lista con todos los usuarios de la base de datos

Hay alguna manera de obtener solamente aquellos Usuarios que pertenecen a la lista? Ya sea desde el **views.py**, **forms.py** o el template directamente?

Para este caso uso una *UpdateView*

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name="dispatch")
class ListUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = List
    form_class = ListForm
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'

    # Al terminar el update nos redirigimos a la pagina, obteniendo su ID
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('lists:update', args=[self.object.id]) + '?ok'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saludos supongamos los siguientes modelos:

```
class Product(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='products/', null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Categories)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Categories(models.Model):
   name =  models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

en tu template podrias iterarlo en un ciclo for:

```
{% for product in object_list %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
    <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ product.price }}</td>
    <td>
        {% for category in product.categories.all %}
            {{ category }}
        {% endfor %}
    </td>
{% endfor %}
```

o sin el ciclo for con el join de esta manera:

```
{% for product in object_list %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
    <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ product.price }}</td>
    <td>{{ product.categories.all|join:", " }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

para mayor detalle del uso de Join: [Join Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#join)

Espero te sirva..!!